# How to get record in unique array Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a table:

```
----------------------
| user_id | marker_id|
----------------------
| 1 | 1 |
--------
| 1 |2 |
--------
| 2 |1 |
--------
| 2 |2 |
--------
| 2 |3 |
--------
| 3 |1 |
--------
```

I want get unique user_id has marker_id =(1,2). Don't get user_id has marker_id = (1,2,3). How to get user_id = 1 and not include user_id =2.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct user_id 
from table_name 
where marker_id in (1,2)
```

Comment: But result include user_id =2. I only want get marker_id in (1,2) and total_marker_id = 2. It means user_id has exactly marker_id = (1,2) not more (1,2,3,4)

Comment: please add your expected result in your question

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `group by`:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having sum(marker_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(marker_id = 2) > 0 and
       sum(marker_id not in (1, 2)) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause tests one of the values.  The first tests for `marker_id = 1` and the `> 0` says there is at least one.  The second similarly tests for `marker_id = 2`.  The third says that there are no other marker ids.

I call this type of query a "set-within-sets" subquery (you are looking for marker ids for each user).  I find that `group by`/`having` is a flexible way to solve these queries.